# Stop runaway regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to stop a runaway regular expression?

I am not interested in suggestions on how to modify it. I know it can be modified so it doesn't break, etc, but I am running a single regex against thousands of inputs, so modifying it means I need to retest it on *all* the inputs. Not very practical.

So the exact question is: **is there some form of timer that I can use to terminate a regex that takes longer than X seconds to complete?**

Comment: You can't actually alarm out of the regex engine, from what my own testing has revealed to me.  However, there is a module: Sys::SigAction which has a function, "`timeout_call`" that will interrupt the regex engine whilst in progress.  However, interrupting the RE engine in progress is not safe, and can cause a seg-fault.

Comment: @DavidO then simple fork should do.

Comment: @mpapec ...by some definitions of "simple". ;)  Yes, `fork` is sometimes a good alternative.  I'll update my answer below to include it as a suggestion.

Comment: @mpapec : No, I think the fork/alarm suggestion is very reasonable.  It's too bad this question was on its way to being closed (hopefully that won't succeed), because it's not a bad question.  The use-case may be of dubious merit, but there are legitimate cases where time-constrained matching is reasonable.  BTW: I think threads have been deprecated in Perl-5.20.

Comment: @DavidO re: `threads have been deprecated in Perl-5.20` world is coming to the end. :)

Comment: @mpapec: "deprecated" was too strong of a word.  Here's the quote from `perldelta` for 5.20: "*Interpreter-based threads are now discouraged...*"

Comment: ###See also
> [How can I safely validate an untrusted regex in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357755/how-can-i-safely-validate-an-untrusted-regex-in-perl/20357964)

Answer (score 10):

Perl's built-in `alarm` is insufficient for breaking out of a long running regular expression because Perl doesn't give opportunities for alarm timeouts inside of internal opcodes.  `alarm` simply cannot penetrate it.

In some cases the most obvious solution is to `fork` a subprocess and time it out after it's gone on too long using `alarm`.  This PerlMonks post demonstrates how to time-out a forked process:  [Re: Timeout on script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=324187)

There is a Perl module on CPAN called [Sys::SigAction](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys%3a%3aSigAction) that has a function called `timeout_call`, which *will* interrupt a long-running regular expression using unsafe signals.  However, the RE engine wasn't designed to be interrupted, and can be left in an unstable state that may lead to seg-faults about 10% of the time.

Here is some example code that demonstrates Sys::SigAction successfully breaking out of the regex engine, as well as demonstrating that Perl's `alarm` is incapable of doing so:

```
use Sys::SigAction 'timeout_call';
use Time::HiRes;


sub run_re {
  my $string = ('a' x 64 ) . 'b';

  if( $string =~ m/(a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*)*[^Bb]$/ ) {
    print "Whoops!\n";
  }
  else {
    print "Ok!\n";
  }
}

print "Sys::SigAction::timeout_call:\n";
my $t = time();
timeout_call(2,\&run_re);
print time() - $t, " seconds.\n";

print "alarm:\n";
$t = time();

eval {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
  alarm 2;
  run_re();
  alarm 0;
};

if( $@ ) {
  die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";
}
else {
  print time() - $t, " seconds.\n";
}
```

The output will be something along the lines of:

```
$ ./mytest.pl
Sys::SigAction::timeout_call:
Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at ./mytest.pl line 11.
2 seconds.
alarm:
Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at ./mytest.pl line 11.
^C
```

You will notice that in the second call -- the one that is supposed to time out with `alarm`, I finally had to `ctrl-C` out of it because `alarm` was inadequate for breaking out of the RE engine.

The big caveat with Sys::SigAction is that even though it is capable of breaking out of a long-running regular expression, because the RE engine wasn't designed for such interruptions, the entire process can become unstable, leading to a segfault.  While it doesn't happen every time, it can happen.  This probably isn't what you want.

I don't know what your regular expression looks like, but if it fits within the syntax allowed by the [RE2 engine](https://code.google.com/p/re2/), you can use the Perl module, [re::engine::RE2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re%3a%3aengine%3a%3aRE2) to work with the RE2 C++ library.  This engine guarantees linear time searches, though it provides less powerful semantics than Perl's built-in engine.  The RE2 approach avoids the whole issue in the first place by providing a linear-time assurance.

However, if you're unable to use RE2 (possibly because your regex's semantics are too demanding for it), the fork/alarm method is probably the safest way to assure you remain in control.

(*By the way, this question, and a version of my answer were crossposted to [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1087822).*)